# Keras load_model with custom objects doesn't work properly when class defined in other file

Tags: tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I got a problem with my custom layer

```
class L2Layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(L2Layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
            self._x = self.add_weight(name='alpha_l2', 
                                    shape=(1,),
                                    initializer='ones',
                                    trainable=True)
        super(L2Layer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return self._x * tf.divide(x, tf.norm(x, ord='euclidean'))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]
```

which is saved in a different .py file, for instance: models.py.

When I am trying to load the model via

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('outputs/test.hdf5', custom_objects={'L2Layer': L2Layer})
```

**I got the error:**

```
NameError: name 'L2Layer' is not defined
```

**Questions**

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In the class file, all of the lines below the first line should be indented.  Does that fix anything?

Comment: Try to use ```tf``` type to save model

Comment: Thanks, @user1321988 . I already have my file indented. I lost the indentation when pasting in StackOverflow. Still not working

Comment: @DachuanZhao I'm saving my model with tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint, but still not working.

Comment: @EmmanuelOvalle , Can you give a google colab for your code ?

Comment: @EmmanuelOvalle And do you define a get_config function in class ```L2Layer``` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a `get_config` in class `L2Layer` .

Read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#saving_custom_objects) for more detail .

Answer (score 0):

you can overcome this error temporarily and load model by running the part of the code wher you defined the class. Run that part

```
class L2Layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(L2Layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self._x = self.add_weight(name='alpha_l2', 
                                shape=(1,),
                                initializer='ones',
                                trainable=True)
    super(L2Layer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

def call(self, x):
    return self._x * tf.divide(x, tf.norm(x, ord='euclidean'))

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape[0]
```

so that this class definition is included in the memory and than try to load the model using same code.